# SSAS Tabular Process Add

Tags: process, ssas, tabular, partition, dimensions

first I´m sorry about my terrible english. But, Anyone knows if :
Process Dimensions or Partitions using option "Process Add" in SSAS tabular bring the updates from source ? Or only new records ?

Answer (score 1):

Process Add only adds new records. If you want to “update” existing records you need to Full process the partitions containing those records.

Comment: Thks Greg. I appreciate your attention.